# Responsive div with background images not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have div container in which two divs with background pictures.I style div container display grid and fix one div bigger than other. I want divs to stack on top (or take width 100%)for small screen size. Want to make it responsive.But not working. In original code I more divs. Here i just included two.

```css
#main {
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.sub {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

#one {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image- 
 vector/floral-seamless-pattern-leaves-cordelia-600w- 1142315438.jpg");

}

#two {
  background-image: url(https://image.shutterstock.com/image- 
 photo/colorful-flower-on-dark-tropical-600w-721703848.jpg)
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #one,
  #two {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="sub" id="one">1</div>
  <div class="sub" id="two">2</div>
```

Comment: this work fine. just remove the spaces from url

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the media query to below:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #main {
        grid-template-columns: auto;
    }

    #one {
        grid-column-end: 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use flex-box it's a lot easier to work with in my opinion. Just add a media query and change the flex-direction to row if you don't want them stacked on bigger screen sizes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sub{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px; /** can be whatever height you want **/
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/suburban-house-royalty-free-image-1584972559.jpg?resize=980:*");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub" id="1"></div>
  <div class="sub" id="2"></div>
</div>
```